# Select Multiple tables for a JDBC project

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

So my sql is very rusty.

I have a project I'm working on, written in Java, for college connected to an oracle DB, I have 6 tables, product, digital product, CD, Artist, Song and song_artist

I want to add, update and delete from these tables simultaneously from within my java program.
So I went about joining them, I'm really not sue if the way I'm trying to this is possible or is the best way, below is my attempt at some of the code, 
bear in mind that the table structure can not be changed.

```
public ResultSet getCD() {
    try {
        String queryString = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCT p, DIGITAL_PRODUCT dp,  CD c, SONG s, ARTIST a, CD_ARTIST ca"
                + "WHERE p.PROD_ID = dp.PROD_ID AND dp.DIG_ID = c.DIG_ID AND c.CD_ID = ca.CD_ID "
                + "AND ca.ARTIST_ID = a.ARTIST_ID AND ca.CD_ID = s.CD_ID"
                + "GROUP BY PROD_ID ";

        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rset = stmt.executeQuery(queryString);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return rset;
}
```

At the moment I'm getting an java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended, I'm guessing this is probably to do with my group by.

Any help or advice really appreciated.

Comment: The error is because you have to `GROUP BY p.PROD_ID` or `dp.PROD_ID` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Changed it to p.PROD_ID, still the same result

Comment: You are also missing spaces (for example after `s.CD_ID`). Note that the join syntax you use is considered deprecated. You should really use explicit joins.

Comment: Could you give me an example of an explicit join using  the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with your query is that you cannot use `select *` together with `group by` this way. If a column that is selected does not appear in the group by clause an aggregate function like `max` must be applied to it in the list. Leo is of course right, to.

Comment: Yeah ok I think that has given me something to work with, I removed the group by and no more errors, I'm not sure that I need the group by at all so I will play around with it a bit more now and see how I get on. thanks for all your input.

Answer (score 3):

your query is just missing a space before the "WHERE" and the "GROUP"

Comment: It may still not work. The query has select "*" and group by has only "PROD_ID"

Comment: Ok so I put the space in and now the error has changed to: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: true. because now, you need some aggregation function to group your results on it. What do you want exactly from your query with the group clause? (so we can help you)

Comment: I'll get back to you on this, I have enough to work with for now, thanks for your help so far.